# Fast Way To Securely Empty Trash in OS 10.4.11

Tags: trash

How can I quickly "empty the trash" using "secure empty trash"? As of now, it takes for ever to
empty large files. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The secure deletion process must over write the files which takes time proportional to the size of the files. There is no faster way. Unless you un-securely delete the files.